# Changing the structure of html with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML with a structure:

```
<a name='data'></a>
<div class='c0'>...</div>
<div class='c4'>...</div>

<a name='data'></a>
<div class='c0'>...</div>
<div class='c4'>...</div>
```

I want to change the structure as following:

```
<a name='data'>
  <div class='c0'>...</div>
  <div class='c4'>...</div>
</a>

<a name='data'>
  <div class='c0'>...</div>
  <div class='c4'>...</div>
</a>
```

I tried to do something to change, but it gives me a wrong structure. How I can do this? Appreciate any help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = open("AAN.HTML").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll(['a', 'div']):
    if item.name == 'a':
        text = item
    if item.name == 'div':
        a.insert(len(a.contents), item)

my_html = str(soup)
print(my_html)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you come across an `<a>`, then set variable `a = item`. 
For the `<div>` that come the `a` variable that was previously set `a.append(item)`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = open("AAN.HTML").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll(['a', 'div']):
    if item.name == 'a':
        a = item
    if item.name == 'div':
        a.append(item)

my_html = str(soup.prettify())
print(my_html)
```